# Cura not allowing full print area to used

Tags: ultimaker-cura

Cura does not seem let the full print area to be used. My printer is a [Lulzbot Mini](https://www.lulzbot.com/store/printers/lulzbot-mini). The design illustrated below can be found [here](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/hBE6Aj2EJMo-skyrail-marble-coster-banked-curve-beta).

[image]


  [image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cura is likely factoring in your skirt. Change the skirt lines to 0 and you might be able to print (`Expert` -> `Switch to full settings`, then click the options button next to "platform adhesion type."). Cura also seems to have an in-built build size offset of about 2 mm. I can't seem to get rid of it in any way other than to change the build size.

Comment: The same happens in MakerWare with a skirt and/or raft

Comment: Click the button next to the dropdown. You will find options for the skirt there. A skirt is not counted as a "platform adhesion type," apparently.

Comment: Setting "Start distance (mm)" to 0 fixed it.  Thanks!

Comment: @Kevin: What do you mean by "in-built build size offset"? Does Cura change the size of a print? Or the position?

Comment: As in, Cura's *actual* computed print space is smaller than appears on the screen. Cura will change the color of objects that are larger than your print  space and not slice them.

Comment: Changing build size does enlarge the printer volume (but not the actual; it is shifted by half the enlargement in X and Y), but, note that this doesn't help for your printer unless you change the X and Y offsets to the end stops as well! You can simply redefine this with `G92` in a start-script for instance.

Answer (score 2):

If you set skirt setting to 'none', it will get you up to full bed area -1 mm at the edges, so, for example, 198x198 instead of 200x200.

You need to go to 'Travel' and set 'Travel avoid distance' to zero to get the full 200x200, or whatever, bed area.