# Cura grey large grey area, almost nothing fits…

Tags: prusa-i3, ultimaker-cura

I can't seem to understand the margins that Cura uses or how to fix them for my machine. Look at this:

[image: Screenshot of Cura, depicting large grey area]

I can't seem to tweak the stuff under machine settings to anything that does this better:

[image: Screenshot of settings]

Maybe a bit of dup of [Cura not allowing full print area to used](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/645/cura-not-allowing-full-print-area-to-used), but I think my case is a lot worse and can't be explained by skirts.

Comment: As Carl points out in [his answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4164/cura-grey-large-grey-area-almost-nothing-fits#answer-4168), could you post your brim/raft/skirt settings?

Comment: You are using Cura 2.5, you should mention it in your question... I see that you have posted this query on [Cura 2.3 - Not using full print area](https://ultimaker.com/en/community/23300-cura-23-not-using-full-print-area) as well... so presumably you have made brim/raft/skirt all visible and set to zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had mistakenly left the setting "one at a time" in print sequence. This meaning the printhead needs a lot of room since it will go back and forth in z.

Cura allocates this extra space even if there's only one object.

Comment: Don't modify your question inside an answer.  Either edit the question or delete it and post a new question.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft is quite right. The answer to your question seems to be that you had "one at a time" selected. It is good that you found a solution to your problem, and that part should remain, in this answer. However, your additional points seem to be another question. It would seem to be best to cut those additional points from *this* answer, and then paste and post them in *another* question, whilst linking back to this question, as reference. Otherwise, people will not be able to address, and answer, your new queries.

Comment: Removed my opinions. Thanks for pointing it out. I guess there's that human need to explain why I didn't think about it :) But it doesn't belong here of course.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like you've got the "brim" set to a very wide value.  I know you said it's not explained by skirts --which, as Greenonline pointed out, is not the same as a brim--, but you didn't post that setting. At the same time, make sure you don't have a 'raft' set up.

One other possibility is that your source file actually contains a very large first layer.  Try looking at the STL file in Meshlab or Meshmixer to see what's actually there.

Comment: +1, but *technically* speaking, a **skirt** isn't *exactly* the same as a **brim**... see [What are main differences between rafts, skirts and brims?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/20/what-are-main-differences-between-rafts-skirts-and-brims)

Comment: @Greenonline thanks - I wasn't actually aware that Cura supported skirts; just brims.

Comment: No brims, skirts or rafts.